# Numero dinamica tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Bueno tengo la siguiente tabla donde agrego y elimino lineas de ella. La quiero hacer mas dinámica al poder eliminar o agregar una linea este se ordene con los numeros de el 1 al infinito de forma correlativa.

Para esto quiero saber si existe alguna funciona donde pueda auto llenar con numeros desde el 1 a infino.

```js
$('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', '.delete_line', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


     
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                 <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando el plugin datatables? Veo que lo estás referenciando pero que no estás generando la tabla con él.

Comment: No estoy utlizando datatable

Comment: Ok. Fíjate que lo tienes referenciado en tu ejemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te puede servir recorrer nuevamente la tabla. Espero haber entendido tu pregunta.

```js
$('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', '.delete_line', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    var i = 1;
    $('#tbl_cotizacion > tbody  > tr').each(function(e) {
      $(this)[0].cells[0].outerHTML='<td>'+ i +'</td>';
        i++;
    });
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


     
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 1 </td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                 <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 2 </td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
              
               <tr>
                <td> 3 </td>
                <td> 10 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: thanks my budda

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien lo que quieres el reordenar la tabla según la segunda columna. Podrías utilizar la función [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) para comparar los textos de la columna:

```js
$('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', '.delete_line', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  reorderTable($("#tbl_cotizacion"));
});

function reorderTable(table){
  let tbody = table.find('tbody');
  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $('td:nth-child(2)', a).text().localeCompare($('td:nth-child(2)', b).text()); 
  }).appendTo(tbody);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


     
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                 <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 1 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 3 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light delete_line'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; Borrar </button> </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: creo que lo que quiere es que se regeneren los numeros, si se elimino la fila 2 de 3 filas 1,2,3 => 1,X,3  entonces que ahora se vea 1,2.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias hacerlo de la siguiente forma sin necesidad de un ID:

```
<table id = 'dsTable' border=1>
      <tr>
         <td> Marcas</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Chevrolet </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="deleteDep" value="Delete" onclick = "deleteRow(this)"  </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td> KIA </td>
         <td>  <input type="button" id ="deleteDep" value="Delete" onclick = "deleteRow(this)" </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
<script>
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
</script>
```

Uso el evento onclick el cual llama a una funcion deleteRow, esta se encarga de eliminar la fila.

Espero te sirva !!